# use of mappedBy in Many to Many relationship in Grails

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am a newbie to Grails and am having a lots of problems in a many to many relationship especially when the mappedBy comes into picture. Here is the exact problem that I am facing. 
I have two domain classes which have a many to many relationship.

```
class Address {
Long id
String addName
static hasMany = [policy: Policy]
static belongsTo=[Policy]
Date lastUpdated
Date dateCreated
}
```

and

```
class Policy {
int id
int policyId
Date lastUpdated
Date dateCreated

static hasMany = [addressSource:Address,addressDestination: AddressSet]
}
```

Now this creates 4 tables, namely : address, policy, policy_src_add and policy_dest_add

The problem that I am facing is with the 'show' view (The views are the standard ones generated by Grails by the generate-views command).

In the show view of Address I can see the Policies that are referenced by policy_dest_add but not the ones that are referenced by policy_src_add.

For ex : Let us assume there is a policy:"PK" which has addressSource:"AS"(lets say id=1)  and a addressDestination :"AD"(lets say : id=2)

When i go to the show view of "AD" (which is /address/show/2 ) I can see the Policy "PK" but when i go to the show view of "AS" (which is /address/show/1 ) I can NOT see the Policy "PK" in it.

Can someone please help me.Is this a view generation problem in case of many to many relationships in grails? Or is it just something I am missing ?I have tried using mappedBy in the Address as follows but to no avail :

static mappedBy = [policy:"addressSource", policy:"addressDestination"]

Thanks a ton,
Manas Shukla

Comment: My understanding of your question is, you are trying to establish a many-to-many relationship and the default scaffolding view is not showing the relationship properly. In which case you would have to use a finder to get all the source and destination addresses separately.